# Quiero eliminar un registro en mi bbdd con php al clicar en el checkbox de eliminar

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Intento borrar mi registro en la bbdd clicando en el checkbox pero no me hace nada con el siguiente código. Debería eliminarme pero no lo hace. Creo que el problema puede venir de $vivienda_id, no me llega a coger el id bien cunado estamos haciendo el checkbox pero no estoy segura. También he intentado quitar el is_Array y si pongo un echo con un 1 o lo que sea si me lo imprime pero una vez que vuelvo a colocar lo de is_Array ni me entra. No se de dónde puede venir el error pero nunca me lo ha eliminado de la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
 
<body>
 
<form method="POST">
    <?php consultar(); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Eliminar Viviendas" name="eliminar"><br>
    <a href="../principal1.php">[Volver a la página principal]</a>
</form>
 
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['eliminar']) && is_array($_POST['eliminar'])) {
        $viviendasAEliminar = $_POST['eliminar'];
        $conexion = conexion();
 
        if ($conexion) {
            foreach ($viviendasAEliminar as $vivienda_id) {
                $vivienda_id = intval($vivienda_id);
 
                $sql = "DELETE FROM viviendas WHERE id = $vivienda_id";
 
                if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "Vivienda con ID $vivienda_id eliminada correctamente.<br>";
                } else {
                    echo "Error al eliminar la vivienda con ID $vivienda_id: " . $conexion->error . "<br>";
                }
            }
 
            $conexion->close();
        }
    }
}
 
function conexion()
{
    $mysqli_connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lindavista");
 
    if ($mysqli_connect->connect_error) {
        echo "Error al conectarse: " . $mysqli_connect->connect_error;
        exit;
    }
    return $mysqli_connect;
}
 
function consultar()
{
    $conexion = conexion();
    if ($conexion) {
 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM viviendas";
 
        $result = $conexion->query($sql);
 
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<table class='table'>";
            echo "<thead>";
            echo "<tr class='table-danger'>";
            echo "<th>TIPO</th>";
            echo "<th>ZONA</th>";
            echo "<th>DORMITORIOS</th>";
            echo "<th>PRECIO</th>";
            echo "<th>TAMAÑO</th>";
            echo "<th>EXTRAS</th>";
            echo "<th>FOTO</th>";
            echo "<th>ELIMINAR</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</thead>";
            echo "<tbody>";
 
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $vivienda = $row["tipo"];
                $zona = $row["zona"];
                $dormitorios = $row["dormitorios"];
                $precio = $row["precio"];
                $tamaño = $row["tamano"];
                $vivienda_id = $row["id"];
 
                if (is_array($row['extras'])) {
                    $extras = implode(", ", $row['extras']);
                } else {
                    $extras = ($row['extras']);
                }
 
                $nombreArchivo = $row["foto"];
                $arrayArchivo = pathinfo($nombreArchivo);
 
                if (isset($arrayArchivo['extension'])) {
                    $extension = $arrayArchivo['extension'];
                } else {
                    $extension = "sin_extension";
                }
                $imagenURL = "imagenes/$nombreArchivo.$extension";
                echo "<tr class='table-primary'>";
                echo "<td>$vivienda</td>";
                echo "<td>$zona</td>";
                echo "<td>$dormitorios</td>";
                echo "<td>$precio</td>";
                echo "<td>$tamaño</td>";
                echo "<td>$extras</td>";
                echo " <td><a href='$imagenURL' target='_blank'>$nombreArchivo</a></td>";
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="eliminar[]" value="' . $vivienda_id . '"></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "No se encontraron resultados.";
        }
    }
 
    $conexion->close();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra. Convendría que inspecciones el HTML para ver si el checkbox se está construyendo con los datos correctos.

Comment: Y no te saldría mejor un botón "**Eliminar**" para cada registro?? A no ser que en esa vista a futuro vayas a tener que eliminar un montonazo de viviendas claro...